# using typedef with NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, typedef

can I use typedef with NSString?  like

```
typedef {
kUserAvatar = @"kUserAvatar",
kGroupAvatar = @"kGroupAvatar",
kWallImage = @"kWallImage",
} lala;
```

rather then

```
 static NSString * const kUserAvatar = @"kUserAvatar";
```

Comment: Why don't you try and find out?

Comment: I am interesting is it correct or not.

Comment: Are you trying to use typedef with NSString? or create s struct with 2 NSStrings?

Comment: I think you may be confusing `typedef` with `enum`. Still, enum values can't be Objective-C objects.

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid syntax in Objective-C (or in C or C++).

I suppose you could do this if you really want:

```
typedef NSString *const NSStringConstPointer;

static NSStringConstPointer
    kUserAvatar = @"kUserAvatar",
    kGroupAvatar = @"kGroupAvatar",
    kWallImage = @"kWallImage";
```

Aside from the `NSString` literals, that is standard C89/C++98 (and all later standards).  However, it doesn't save you much and makes it harder to move individual definitions to other places, should you need to.

Comment: This is a valid and clever middle ground/solution for the question as written, but I think it'd be better to reinforce the standard/accepted way of doing things rather than encouraging nonstandard techniques.